# Laravel `array_pluck` on any key

Tags: php, laravel

Is possible use something like `array_pluck($array, 'users.*.id')`?

Imagine that I have:

```
$array = [
    'users' => [
        [ 'id' => 1 ],
        [ 'id' => 2 ],
        [ 'id' => 3 ],
    ]
];
```

And I want get `[1, 2, 3]`.

I tried something like: `users.*.id`, `users.id` and `users..id`, but nothing worked.

Comment: `array_pluck($array['users'], 'id')`. The function only supports a single dimension array.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**From Laravel 5.7**, you may use the `Arr::pluck()` helper.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;

Arr::pluck($array['users'], 'id')
```

---

Use `array_pluck($array['users'], 'id')`

The function only supports a single dimensional array. It will search for keys in the array which match the second parameter; which in your case is 'id'. You'll note that the array you're searching in your examples only has a key named `users` and none with the name `id`.

Using `$array['users']` means pluck looks through that array and subsequently finds keys named `id` on each element.

Comment: I don't understand.  Why wouldn't a developer just use the direct/native/helper-less `array_column($array['users'], 'id')` instead?  Can you explain the benefit of a wrapper in this case?  Furthermore, https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/helpers#method-array-pluck seems to indicate the ability to navigate deeper data with dot syntax.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Laravel collections](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/collections) to achieve something like this.

```
$data = collect($array['users']);
$ids = $data->pluck('id');
return $ids;
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/helpers#method-array-pluck.
Don't recreate helpers that already exist ;)

Comment: I had used `array_pluck(array_get($array, 'users'), 'id')` in 2015. Read the original post. Anyway, I'm grateful for your interest in helping. :D